# including external php file into php mailer body

Tags: email, php, html

```
     if($_POST['mail'])
    {
 $to_name = $rows['username'];
$to = $rows['email'];
$subject = "Invoice";



   $from_name = "abc.com";
 $from = "noreply.com@abc.com";

 // phpMailer
 require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
 $mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //enable php socks to make SSL it working
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';    
$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";

$mail->FromName = $from_name;
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->AddAddress($to, $to_name);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = include'invoice.php';  
$mail->IsHTML(true);    
$result = $mail->Send();
}
?>
```

Rather showing me php page its display nothing in mail  !

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 6):

This is the correct way to do this:

```
ob_start();
include('invoice.php');
$mail->Body = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Instead of  `ob_get_contents();` you could also simply use `ob_get_clean();` and remove `ob_end_clean();` as `ob_get_clean();` actually does both operations. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php